# Navicat Essentials (11); Can't connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, macos, zend-framework, navicat

I have just updated to Navicat Essentials 11 on Mac. I'm using Zend server and now the old settings don't work:

General tab:

```
Host name: localhost
Port: 3036 (tried also with 3306)
```

And under advanced tab:

```
Use socket file: /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

I get an error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (1)
```

I copied mysql.sock file to /tmp and tried with with default socket settings:

```
Use socket file: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I also got an error

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Facts

- can't connect with Navicat Essentials 11
- mysql server is running
- username and password are correct
- socket file worked in previous version

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'ma answering my own question:

I made a http tunnel file (Navicat -> Connection Properties -> Save Tunnel script as...) and copied in on the root of local server. Now I'm connectig via http tunnel:

```
http://localhost/ntunnel_mysql.php
```

and everything seems to work fine.

I had an error "protocol mismatch" when trying to connect at first time. Full restart of computer solved this problem too (?).